# Keras binary image classifier returns 1 class even with training set

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, classification

Im currently building a binary image classifier using keras with Python.
The data are split evenly for both training and test.

I've been having problem with it with an accuracy of 50%, which means that it was guessing one class during training.

I introduced gradient clipping, BatchNormalization with momentum, and Leaky Relu to solve some of the issues. With these, I got a classifier with high training accuracy (Realms of 95%) and low loss(Around 0.05).

The val_acc is usually 0.1 lower than training accuracy and a val_loss of around 0.3. This suggests overfitting.

I decided to just try to predict with the training images, where they should at least predict those correctly in any case. However, it only predicts 1 class even on training set.

Below is my model:

```
    classifier = Sequential()


    classifier.add(Conv2D(8, (5, 5), input_shape = (256, 204, 3), activation = 'linear', padding = 'same'))
    classifier.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.001))
    classifier.add(BatchNormalization(momentum = 0.1))
    classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))
    classifier.add(Dropout(0.5))

    classifier.add(Conv2D(8, (5, 5), activation = 'linear', padding = 'same'))
    classifier.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.001))
    classifier.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.1))
    classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))
    classifier.add(Dropout(0.5))

    classifier.add(Flatten())


   classifier.add(Dense(units = 128, activation = 'linear'))
   classifier.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.001))
   classifier.add(Dense(units = 1, activation = 'sigmoid'))


   adam = optimizers.Adam(lr = 0.001, decay = 1e-2, clipvalue = 1, clipnorm = 1)
  classifier.compile(optimizer = adam, loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])
```

I've made the model as simple as possible to prevent overfitting. 
My images are to classifier is there are droplets of water on a piece of cloth. Which looks a bit like blood stains on a wall.

Does anyone have any idea why this is the case, or what should I try next?

Comment: What do you mean exactly that it predicts only one class? Is your dataset balanced, like approximately same amount of positive and negative class examples?

Comment: So lets say I have dataset A and B, the model trains to acc of 0.95 with low loss.

When I use the training set data, if I use an image from A, it will predict B, when I use an image from B, it'll predict B. So it's always stuck to 1 particular class. This is the case for training set, test set, and even unseen images

Both A and B have 1000 training images and 200 test images each

Comment: What about class balance in the dataset?

Comment: Sorry, I mean class. Class A has 1000 training,200 test, likewise for B